# How does particle acceleration amplitude relate to particle resonant frequency? (ULTRASOUND)

Tags: waves, acceleration, acoustics, ultrasound

In diagnostic ultrasound the acoustic pulse propagates in a non-linear fashion (Duck 2002).

I have been taught that:

1. The increase in wave velocity in the compressive phase increases particle acceleration/velocity amplitude.
2. Through this a portion of the energy is converted to harmonic resonant frequency.

How does an increase in particle acceleration/velocity amplitude produce harmonic resonant frequency?

I found the following picture from https://physics.info/intensity/ which explains this in a lot of detail, but it's far beyond my understanding. You may find it helpful to explain the concept more easily:

[image: Equation table from Physics.info page on intensity]

References:

Duck F 2002 "Nonlinear acoustics in diagnostic ultrasound" Ultrasound Med Biol. PMID: 11879947

Comment: Can you, please, provide the complete reference for [Duck 2002]?

Comment: I've just added that for you